# UITextView text space go smaller during rezise

Tags: ios, uitextview, frame

I'd like to enable the user to resize an UITextView. I display a button in the bottom rigth corner of the UITextView such as when the user moves it, the UITextView follow it and is resized.

This is works fine but the text space has a strange behaviour. The text space seems to get smaller and smaller during the resize. So if I resize a lot, go to a big frame and then to a small frame, the text space has become smaller than the frame.

```
- (id) init{//My subclass of UITextView
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        //Resize button
        //Init ResizeButton
        self.resizeButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];

        //Image
        [self.resizeButton setImageForAllState:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Isosceles-right-triangle.png"]];

        //Target
        [self.resizeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
        [self.resizeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];

        //Add to view
        [self addSubview:resizeButton];

        //Self
        //text font
        [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"papyrus" size:17]];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)wasDragged:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


//  NSLog(@"wasDragged");// get the touch
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:button] anyObject];

    // get delta
    CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:button];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:button];
    CGFloat delta_x = location.x - previousLocation.x;
    CGFloat delta_y = location.y - previousLocation.y;

    // move button
    button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x + delta_x,
                                button.center.y + delta_y);


    self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width+ delta_x, self.frame.size.height+ delta_y);

}
```

The view is also draggable

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Calculate offset
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    float dx = pt.x - startLocation.x;
    float dy = pt.y - startLocation.y;
    CGPoint newcenter = CGPointMake(self.center.x + dx, self.center.y + dy);

    // Set new location
    self.center = newcenter;

}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Calculate and store offset, and pop view into front if needed
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    startLocation = pt;
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


}
```

---

EDIT

Before resizing
[image: Before resizing]

Resizing
[image: Resizing]

Back to original size
[image: Back to original size]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have this problem too. The soliution is to subclass UITextView and override setFrame: method. Before setting your wanted frame, set CGRectZero frame for textView. It will fix your problem. Code bellow.

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:CGRectZero];
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could do one of two things:

First: turn off the 'Adjust to fit' of the control

```
textfield.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
```

Second:  Hardcode a font size into the code

```
textfield.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"desired font name" size:10];
```

Comment: 1. "textfield.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;" for an UITextView ? 2. I'm doing that in the init method.